# Mysql INSERT INTO not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I made an admission form and trying to save the information into database. it is working but a section which is about academic record in giving some problem.

```
    <!----- Admission ---------------------------------------------------------->
    <tr>
    <td width="180">Admission in Class / Group</td>
    <td width="492"><input name="class" type="text" size="30" id="class"/></td>
    </tr>
            <!----- Name ---------------------------------------------------------->
        <tr>
        <td width="180">Name </td>
        <td width="490"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" /></td>
        </tr>

        <!----- Gender ---------------------------------------------------------->
        <tr>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="gender" id="gender" size="20" /></td>
        </tr>

        <!----- Date of Birth ---------------------------------------------------------->
        <tr>
        <td>Date of Birth</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="date-of-birth" id="date-of-birth" size="20" /></td>
        </tr>


        <!----- Mark of Identification -------------------------------------------------------->
        <tr>
        <td>Mark of Identification</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mark-of-identification" id="mark-of-identification" size="30" /></td>
        </tr>

<!----- Academic Record -------------------------------------------------------->

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tr>
  <th width="9%">EXAM</th>
  <th width="11%">SCHOOL / COLLEGE</th>
  <th width="8%">YEAR</th>
  <th width="10%">TOTAL MARKS</th>
  <th width="11%">MARKS OBTAINED</th>
  <th width="12%">GRADE / DIV</th>
  <th width="15%">% OF MARKS</th>
  <th width="24%">MAJOR SUBJECTS</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="exam" id="ssc" size="7" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="ssc-school" id="ssc-school" size="10" /></td>
  <td><input name="ssc-year" type="text" id="ssc-year" value="" size="7" /></td>
  <td><input name="ssc-total-marks" type="text" id="ssc-total-marks" value="" size="5" /></td>
  <td><input name="ssc-marks" type="text" id="ssc-marks" value="" size="5" /></td>
  <td><input name="ssc-grade" type="text" id="ssc-grade" value="" size="5" /></td>
  <td><input name="ssc-percentage" type="text" id="ssc-percentage" value="" size="5" /></td>
  <td><input name="ssc-sub" type="text" id="ssc-sub" value="" size="10" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="exam2" id="ssc" size="7" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="ssc-ii-school" id="ssc-ii-school" size="10" /></td>
  <td><input name="ssc-year-two" type="text" id="ssc-year-two" value="" size="7" /></td>
  <td><input name="ssc-ii-total-marks" type="text" id="ssc-ii-total-marks" value="" size="5" />        </td>
  <td><input name="ssc-ii-marks" type="text" id="ssc-ii-marks" value="" size="5" /></td>
  <td><input name="ssc-ii-grade" type="text" id="ssc-ii-grade" value="" size="5" /></td>
  <td><input name="ssc-ii-percentage" type="text" id="ssc-ii-percentage" value="" size="5" /> </td>
  <td><input name="ssc-sub2" type="text" id="ssc-sub2" value="" size="10" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="exam3" id="ssc" size="7" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="o-level-school" id="o-level-school" size="10" /></td>
  <td><input name="o-level" type="text" id="o-level" value="" size="7" /></td>
  <td><input name="o-level-total-marks" type="text" id="o-level-total-marks" value="" size="5" /> </td>
  <td><input name="o-level-marks" type="text" id="o-level-marks" value="" size="5" /></td>
  <td><input name="o-level-grade" type="text" id="o-level-grade" value="" size="5" /></td>
  <td><input name="o-level-percentage" type="text" id="o-level-percentage" value="" size="5" /></td>
  <td><input name="o-level-sub" type="text" id="o-level-sub" value="" size="10" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><input type="text" name="exam4" id="ssc" size="7" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="hssc-school" id="hssc-school" size="10" /></td>
  <td><input name="hssc-year" type="text" id="hssc-year" value="" size="7" /></td>
  <td><input name="hssc-total-marks" type="text" id="hssc-total-marks" value="" size="5" /></td>
  <td><input name="hssc-marks" type="text" id="hssc-marks" value="" size="5" /></td>
  <td><input name="hssc-grade" type="text" id="hssc-grade" value="" size="5" /></td>
  <td><input name="hssc-percentage" type="text" id="hssc-percentage" value="" size="5" /></td>
  <td><input name="hssc-sub" type="text" id="hssc-sub" value="" size="10" /></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

The above section is the part of the admission form. I want that if nothing is typed in the form nothing should be saved in the database. if user enter one or two record one or two record should be saved only.

I am trying this

do_admission.php:

```
$class = $_POST['class'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$date_of_birth = $_POST['date-of-birth'];
$mark_of_identification = $_POST['mark-of-identification'];
$exam = $_POST['exam'];
$ssc_school = $_POST['ssc-school'];
$ssc_year = $_POST['ssc-year'];
$ssc_total_marks = $_POST['ssc-total-marks'];
$ssc_marks = $_POST['ssc-marks'];
$ssc_grade = $_POST['ssc-grade'];
$ssc_percentage = $_POST['ssc-percentage'];
$ssc_sub = $_POST['ssc-sub'];
$exam2 = $_POST['exam2'];
$ssc_ii_school = $_POST['ssc-ii-school'];
$ssc_year_two = $_POST['ssc-year-two'];
$ssc_ii_total_marks = $_POST['ssc-ii-total-marks'];
$ssc_ii_marks = $_POST['ssc-ii-marks'];
$ssc_ii_grade = $_POST['ssc-ii-grade'];
$ssc_ii_percentage = $_POST['ssc-ii-percentage'];
$ssc_sub2 = $_POST['ssc-sub2'];
$exam3 = $_POST['exam3'];
$o_level_school = $_POST['o-level-school'];
$o_level = $_POST['o-level'];
$o_level_total_marks = $_POST['o-level-total-marks'];
$o_level_marks = $_POST['o-level-marks'];
$o_level_grade = $_POST['o-level-grade'];
$o_level_percentage = $_POST['o-level-percentage'];
$o_level_sub = $_POST['o-level-sub'];
$exam4 = $_POST['exam4'];
$hssc_school = $_POST['hssc-school'];
$hssc_year = $_POST['hssc-year'];
$hssc_total_marks = $_POST['o-level-marks'];
$hssc_marks = $_POST['hssc-marks'];
$hssc_grade = $_POST['hssc-grade'];
$hssc_percentage = $_POST['hssc-percentage'];
$hssc_sub = $_POST['hssc-sub'];

$sql1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `school`.`students` (`S_No`, `Name`, `Father_Name`, `Class`, `Gender`, `Mark_of_identification`, `Date_of_birth`) VALUES (NULL,  '$name', '$father_name', '$class', '$gender', '$mark_of_identification');") or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
```

the above query is working fine.
i want the following query to work only if the field is fill is it is left empty nothing should save in the database.

```
$sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `school`.`academic` (`S_No`, `Exam`, `School`, `Year`, `Total_marks`, `Marks_obtained`, `Grade`, `Percentage`,`Major_subjects`, `Roll_no`) VALUES (NULL, '$exam', '$ssc_school', '$ssc_year', '$ssc_total_marks','$ssc_marks', '$ssc_grade', '$ssc_percentage', '$ssc_sub', '$roll_number');") or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());

if($sql1 && $sql2) {
    $myURL = 'success.php?sType=insert';
    header('Location: '.$myURL);
    exit;
} else 
    echo "Try again!";
```

Please guide me where to do changes. the $sql2 query should work only if it is filled if it is left empty the other information should be saved and in academic table there should be no information.
Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, escape your POST parameters to prevent MySQL injection.

Comment: _number');") or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error()); remove the comma before die

Comment: '$mark_of_identification');") why are you using a semicolon after '$mark_of_identification')

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: you want that your query only work, when all the feild are filled??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to validate all fields then you can use `if` before insertion

Example:

```
if($exam != "" && $ssc_school != "" && $ssc_year != "") {
    $sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `school`.`academic` (`S_No`, `Exam`, `School`, `Year`, `Total_marks`, `Marks_obtained`, `Grade`, `Percentage`,`Major_subjects`, `Roll_no`) VALUES (NULL, '$exam', '$ssc_school', '$ssc_year', '$ssc_total_marks','$ssc_marks', '$ssc_grade', '$ssc_percentage', '$ssc_sub', '$roll_number');") or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: what to write if $exam ==''

Comment: You want to execute sql2 only if the $exam has any values right ??

Comment: Then you can use this if condition to to check $exam has any values. only if the sql query execute. Do you have any other issues ??

Comment: i tried if($exam!='') Sql2=.................... else { if ($sql1) echo "succesfully updated" }

Comment: still I didn't get you what you are trying to do .. Im totally confused now. Can you make it clear ?? what actually trying to do ??